# Form expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session

In my form I have a timer that is inside a radajaxpanel. This timer is used to do autosaving of the form every 1 minute.

Now my problem is whenever the autosaved is called it is renewing the session timeout. but what I need is to display a notification after an hour of being idle (ask the user to renew the session or else I will logout the user) and ignore the autosave session timeout updation.

Update:

Here's the code

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"  OnTick="AutoSaveNotificationCallBackUpdate" Interval="60000" />

</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

The AutoSaveNotificationCallBackUpdate will do a postback thus resetting my session timeout.

Comment: what is your code used?without viewing code is hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can save following code to `interval.js`

```
if(window.intervals)
    ;
else {
    function Interval() {
        var instance=this;
        var a=[];

        Interval.toString=function () {
            return '[Interval]';
        }

        instance.toString=function () {
            return '[object Interval]';
        }

        instance.Register=function (x, code, delay) {
            a[x]=setInterval(code, delay);
        }

        instance.Deregister=function (x) {
            if(x in a)
                clearInterval(a[x]);
        }
    }

    window.intervals=new Interval();
}
```

Then include it with

```
<script src='interval.js'></script>
```

or

```
<script src='YourSubfolder/interval.js'></script>
```

In your page, you can register an interval:

```
intervals.Register('YourIntervalName', YourMethod, millisecondsInterval);
```

or deregister it:

```
intervals.Deregister('YourIntervalName');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer on client side. Here is the sample code, not exactly but can help you to figure out what to do.

```
var timer;

function initTimer(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
         if(!confirm("Do you want to continue?")) {
              // do some postback to logout, e.g. trigger a logout button 
         }
         else 
              initTimer();
    }, 36000);
}

// in this case, if user does not click in an hour, 
// the confirm dialog will display.
document.onclick = function(){
    // reset the timer every time user click on page
    initTimer();
});

window.onload = function(){
    initTimer();
});
```